# Unable list my One Plus Two in Debug device list android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, oneplustwo

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.3. I'm unable to detect the device for debugging purposes. I have installed Google Drivers in my studio and my OS is Windows 8.1. In Device Manager it is shown as ONE A2003 and the drivers are up to date.

Comment: Try this http://adbdriver.com/.

Comment: Ensure USB debugging is on.

Comment: @AbhriyaRoy Usb debugging is enabled